# WPF Binding 2 Columns to ListView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyTitleBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
<ListBox x:Name="MyInfoBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

In C#:

```
 MyTitleBox.ItemsSource = new List<string>(new string[] {"ID:", "Info:", "More Info:"});
 MyInfoBox.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<string>(MyMainInfo.ToString().Split(',').ToList<string>());
```

I currently have 2 list boxes next to each other because I need to handle their ItemsSource programmatically.

I know there must be a better way to merge the two. Essentially the list box "on the left" is the titles like ID: and the list box "on the right" is the information.

I thought I could do something like MyTitleBox.Columns.Add like I've seen but it won't let me do .Columns. I'm using .NET 4.

Comment: Please read about `ItemTemplate` and `DataTemplate`. This [link](http://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html) will get you started.

Comment: I have. My issue with that is that it needs to be defined in XAML as opposed to programmatically.

Comment: That's what i proposed. ItemTemplate is for XAML only.

Comment: I'm setting the ItemsSource programmatically. I need to be able to set the data source in code because the data source doesnt exist prior. The DataTemplate is having me set the data source in XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with a more MVVM approach:

**Domain (The type of items you want to put in your list):**

```
public class Movie : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            if (_title != value)
            {
                _title = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
            }                
        }
    }

    private string _info;

    public string Info
    {
        get { return _info; }
        set
        {
            if (_info != value)
            {
                _info = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("Info");
            }                
        }
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<Movie> _movies;

    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of movies.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<Movie> Movies
    {
        get { return _movies; }
        set
        {
            if (_movies != value)
            {
                _movies = value;

                RaisePropertyChanged("Movies");
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Movies = new ObservableCollection<Movie>();

        Movies.Add(new Movie() { Title = "Gravity", Info = "Gravity is about..." });
        Movies.Add(new Movie() { Title = "Avatar", Info = "Avatar is about..." });
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Title}" /><Run Text=" - " /><Run Text="{Binding Info}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Click To Change Info" Margin="5" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MyViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ViewModel = new MyViewModel();

        DataContext = ViewModel;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Movie movie = ViewModel.Movies.FirstOrDefault();

        if (movie != null)
        {
            movie.Info = "This is the new information";
        } 
    }
}
```

Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged allows the code to notify the UI when something changes.

If you test this code out you will see that clicking the button updates the info for the first movie, and this changed is immediately reflected in the UI. *(Normally you would use a convention like Commands for handling the button click, but for simplicity I did it this way)*

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you but okay, I do that, but now how do you set the binding? .ItemsSource = list doesn't do anything anymore because of {Binding Title} and {Binding Info}. How do you set that programmatically in C# and not XAML?

Comment: What object are you working with?  Is this a movie or something with title and info?  To be honest the way you are applying the items is not great.

Comment: So I have 2 list of strings. List A is the Titles and List B is the info that corresponds with the title in a particular order. List B's strings are constantly being changed every X amount of seconds. They don't exist when the program starts. They're just like how I put in the OP. So myAList[0] corresponds with myBList[0] for example (ID: 25), its the first item in the collection which is bound to the List View. Which is why right now I have them side by side, but thats not efficient at all or nice looking for that matter. I'm trying to learn how to clean that up.

Comment: I'll give you an example of the preferred way to do it, meaning using an MVVM approach.

Comment: Thank you that would be incredibly helpful. I've been learning MVVM as I go but its not abundantly clear how I can use it in this particular situation. I just know that anything is better than some n^2 concatenation of 200+ values just to make it look pretty. An example would be invaluable.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It just seems bizarre to me that I cant just say okay - ListView with 2 columns. Column one you get ItemSource of myListA and Column two you get ItemSource of myListB. MVVM seems to do a ton of wrapping with 4x as much code. But I suppose the responsiveness of the observable class is nice. Perhaps its just my lack of fundamentals with WPF that makes it so obscure for me.

Comment: Not with a straight list view. You can use a GridView in a ListView.  Which I probably should have recommended.  Here is a link with the info on how to do that:  http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/

Comment: Thanks for that as well. I figured I might as well try learning more MVVM and it worked perfectly. I'll keep that other listview with the embedded grid for safe keeping though! Much thanks.