# How to bind an Observable Collection to a ListView

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, observablecollection, win-universal-app

I've set up the binding of a ListView following this example, [binding to observable collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683413/wpf-binding-2-columns-to-listview) but when I run the application the collection values aren't displayed in the ListView.

The output window isn't throwing any binding errors, so not sure what the binding error could be.
Also I've set a breakpoint on the list before its sent to the second VM and it's populated, ie, not null.

My guess is that the list is null in the second VM as it's not being initialized properly after being passed over.

Can anyone advise how to debug the ListView being empty?

This is the binding set in the View:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AddedSubjectGradePairsCopy}" Height="400" Margin="0,0,0,-329" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{Binding Subject}" /><Run Text=" - " /><Run Text="{Binding Points}" />
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

The data context for the View is set as follows in the code behind:

```
namespace LC_Points.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class ViewSubjectGradePage : Page
    {
        private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;

        private ViewSubjectGradeViewModel ViewModel;

        public ViewSubjectGradePage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
            this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
            this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;

            ViewModel = new ViewSubjectGradeViewModel();
            this.DataContext = ViewModel;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the <see cref="NavigationHelper"/> associated with this <see cref="Page"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
        {
            get { return this.navigationHelper; }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Populates the page with content passed during navigation.  Any saved state is also
        /// provided when recreating a page from a prior session.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">
        /// The source of the event; typically <see cref="NavigationHelper"/>
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that provides both the navigation parameter passed to
        /// <see cref="Frame.Navigate(Type, Object)"/> when this page was initially requested and
        /// a dictionary of state preserved by this page during an earlier
        /// session.  The state will be null the first time a page is visited.</param>
        private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Preserves state associated with this page in case the application is suspended or the
        /// page is discarded from the navigation cache.  Values must conform to the serialization
        /// requirements of <see cref="SuspensionManager.SessionState"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event; typically <see cref="NavigationHelper"/></param>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that provides an empty dictionary to be populated with
        /// serializable state.</param>
        private void NavigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region NavigationHelper registration

        /// <summary>
        /// The methods provided in this section are simply used to allow
        /// NavigationHelper to respond to the page's navigation methods.
        /// <para>
        /// Page specific logic should be placed in event handlers for the  
        /// <see cref="NavigationHelper.LoadState"/>
        /// and <see cref="NavigationHelper.SaveState"/>.
        /// The navigation parameter is available in the LoadState method 
        /// in addition to page state preserved during an earlier session.
        /// </para>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Provides data for navigation methods and event
        /// handlers that cannot cancel the navigation request.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And receiving the list in the ViewSubjectGradeVM  via the constructor:

```
namespace LC_Points.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewSubjectGradeViewModel 
    {


        public ViewSubjectGradeViewModel()
        {


        }

         /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewSubjectGradeViewModel class.
        /// </summary>
        public ViewSubjectGradeViewModel(IEnumerable<ScoreModel> addedSubjectGradePairs)
        {
            this.AddedSubjectGradePairsCopy = addedSubjectGradePairs;

        }


        //Property for collection passed from MainViewModel
        public IEnumerable<ScoreModel> AddedSubjectGradePairsCopy { get; set; }


    }
}
```

And this is the backing Model for the List being passed from the MainVM to the ViewSubjectGradeVM:

```
namespace LC_Points.Model
{
    public class ScoreModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        // The name of the subject.
        public string Subject { get; set; }


        // The points paired with each grade type.
        public int Points { get; set; }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you set the `DataContext`?

Comment: I've set the data context in the code behind of the View, will post an edit now.

Comment: Yes, but you call the default ctor so `AddedSubjectGradePairsCopy` is null.

Comment: okay I see that now, I just need to get rid of this then? http://hastebin.com/oretezoqot.cs

Comment: Nope I removed the default constructor, but the ListView still doesn't show any contents, any other ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't remove default ctor. You need something like this             `ViewModel = new ViewSubjectGradeViewModel(GetScoreModels());
            this.DataContext = ViewModel;` instead of `ViewModel = new ViewSubjectGradeViewModel();
            this.DataContext = ViewModel;`

Comment: So I think I get what your getting at, I need to specify the parameter that my ViewSubjectGradeViewModel takes. I've tried the following but it tells me http://hastebin.com/ohihameyos.tex and this is my attempt:
https://gist.github.com/BrianJVarley/87a051d400ea1c7ffcfb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. Of course, your model should comes form some source which you should map to your viewmodel. But this illustrates you the way to set correct datacontext.

```
var scoremodels = new List<ScoreModel>
{
    new ScoreModel {Subject = "Subj1", Points = 6},
    new ScoreModel {Subject = "Subj2", Points = 3},
    new ScoreModel {Subject = "Subj3", Points = 8},
}
ViewModel = new ViewSubjectGradeViewModel(scoreModels);
this.DataContext = ViewModel;
```

Comment: Okay if I understand correctly, I should define the "thing" that is being passed from the MainVM to this VM. But when I try the following in the ViewSubjectGradePage code behind, the compiler tells me the list doesn't exist in the current context.


 `            ViewModel = new ViewSubjectGradeViewModel(AddedSubjectGradePairs);
`

AddedSubjectGradePairs is the list being passed from the MainVM that is composed from the ScoreModel.

Comment: What you have tried? Show ViewSubjectGradePage code.

Comment: This is what I've tried, but compiler tells me that the list doesn't exist the current context, which is true as the list is in my MainVM. The list is an Observable Collection of type ScoreModel, which is my data model. My ViewSubjectGradePage code: https://gist.github.com/BrianJVarley/87a051d400ea1c7ffcfb and this is the Main VM where I pass the list over to that page's VM in the viewGradesCommand RelayCommand: https://gist.github.com/BrianJVarley/3dd6e164029aeb67263d

Comment: I didn't see where do you have created `MainViewModel`. Also the `AddedSubjectGradePairs` isn't accessible from `ViewSubjectGradePage`.

Comment: This is the MainViewModel where the list is created and passed to the other VM:  http://hastebin.com/alirebanup.cs

Comment: Your collection is emply. `AddedSubjectGradePairs = new ObservableCollection<ScoreModel>();`

Comment: The collection isn't empty after I add pairs to it when calling the AddGrade command.

Comment: `ViewSubjectGradeViewModel subjectGradeObj = new ViewSubjectGradeViewModel(AddedSubjectGradePairs);` This line of code is irrelevant because you had lost the reference to `subjectGradeObj`.